# gte is only showing objects for this month (equal to) and not greater than

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-3.0

I'm going to try to show you this without exposing customer data

Query:

```
Booking.objects.filter(startTime__year__gte=2020, startTime__month__gte=7,startTime__day__gte=27, depositPaid=True).order_by('startTime')
```

This should show all bookings from July 27, inclusive, onward into the future with no bounds. However, the bounds is on the 8th month. None of the bookings for August are showing.

If I run:

```
Booking.objects.filter(startTime__year__gte=2020, startTime__month__gte=8,startTime__day__gte=1, depositPaid=True).order_by('startTime')
```

Then I do get all the bookings in August. I don't understand why `startTime__month__gte=7` doesn't show August.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering by `day__gte=27` will only return results where the day of the month is 27 or greater no matter what the month is, dates in August where the day is less than 27 will not be returned.

If you want to filter results after a certain date you should do it as a single query on the column, not as individual queries on the date parts.

```
import datetime
Booking.objects.filter(startTime__gte=datetime.date(2020, 7, 27), depositPaid=True).order_by('startTime')
```